# Accessing fixtures (e.g., capsys) from a parametrized test

Tags: python, pytest

I'm having trouble accessing fixtures (in this case, capsys) from within a parametrized test. Currently I'm using a dummy fixture to make this work:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def params(request):
    from collections import namedtuple
    return namedtuple('Params', 'input output')(*request.param)

@pytest.mark.parametrize('params', [
    ('a', '1a\n'),
    ('b', '1b\n'),
], indirect=True)
def test_output(capsys, params):
    print('1' + params.input)
    out, err = capsys.readouterr()
    assert out == params.output
```

Is there a way to rewrite this code without the `params` fixture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply remove the `indirect` parameter:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize('params', [
    ('a', '1a\n'),
    ('b', '1b\n'),
])
def test_output(capsys, params):
    inp, expected = params
    print('1' + inp)
    out, err = capsys.readouterr()
    assert out == expected
```

But better approach would be to make `parametrize` pass arguments directly by names:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize('inp, expected', [
    ('a', '1a\n'),
    ('b', '1b\n'),
])
def test_output(capsys, inp, expected):
    print('1' + inp)
    out, err = capsys.readouterr()
    assert out == expected
```

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing... when I was trying to get this to work, I'm sure I saw errors about an incorrect number of arguments being passed to the test, but obviously this example works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Great explanation, thank you. It's still a bit * waves hands * magic to me, how pytest knows which arg is capsys, and which is the fixture, since there's no keyword args involved...

Comment: @eggonlegs It simply checks argument's name in the function's signature, AFAIK.